# connect databricks in GCP with secret manager

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, databricks, google-secret-manager

I am trying to get a a secret from google secret manager in Databricks, but I get the following error:

PermissionDenied: 403 Permission 'secretmanager.versions.access' denied for resource

This is my code:

```
from google.cloud import secretmanager

def access_secret_version(project_id, secret_id, version_id="latest"):
    # Create the Secret Manager client.
    client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()

    # Build the resource name of the secret version.
    name = f"projects/{project_id}/secrets/{secret_id}/versions/{version_id}"

    # Access the secret version.
    response = client.access_secret_version(request={"name": name})

    # Return the decoded payload.
    return response.payload.data.decode('UTF-8')
```

I give secret manager permissions to databricks account but the error persist, any help would be appreciated
Thanks.